# Default page on IIS, ie and opera showing right but others not

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox, iis, opera

I am using windows 7 bit 64. Opera and IE are showing the right default page as  ://localhost/, but GoogleChrome and FireFox are trying to show some other page which exists at present no where in wwwroot in inetpub.

I thought that FireFox and Chrome may be trying to show that page from some other  server programme, but when I deleted wwwroot from my pc, they stopped showing any page as  ://localhost.

I am finding not any logic behind the above occurrence, kindly help me to know that why FireFox and Chrome are not showing logically expected Default page at IIS as  ://localhost.